# Using Logger in DI context C#

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection

I know that topic has quite a lot of resources, but when reading about it I feel like I am missing (at least) one thing.

So I'll make a TLDR of what I think that I understand and what it implies, but then if anyone can pinpoint to me where I am wrong / what I am missing, I'd be glad.

A bit of context first :
I am working in c# in a solution containing several projects :
A class library that is the core
Several UI/CLI projects that rely on it.

From my understanding:

The ILoggerFactory will then instantiate ILogger, so passing the factory in the dependency tree sounds like the good way to do.

My goal being that each different UI can define it's factory with different settings/LoggingProvider

PS: I expect to use the default Microsoft.Extensions.Logging implementations.

But then comes the tricky part, if I want to use C# DI framework, I'm supposed to do something like this in the entry point of my class library

```
//I want to pass the factory as an input parameter
public Worker(ILoggingFactory factory)
    {
        //this is the way I found to create an application builder in order to pass dependencies
        var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();
        builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
        builder.Logging.AddConsole();
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
        var host = builder.Build();
        host.Start();

        //this activator utilities is super weird but didnt find better
        m_myObject = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ObjectType>(host.Services);
    }
```

But it is obviously very wrong, because I cant use the factory I pass as a parameter.

The Ideas I have to fix that but that looks wrong :

- Passing a IServiceCollection, but then I cant instantiate my classes down the dependency tree automatically using the DI, which doesnt bring anything compared to manually setting the ILoggingFactory.
- passing the builder as a parameter

I know I am missing something but cant figure out what,
Thank you for reading through :)

**EDIT:**
After reading answers, I uderstand that the issue here is to use the DI Container in my class library and not at the entry point.

[image: example]

In my example I should then create the DI container in the entry points (so at 3 different places, where I can define different logging settings etc) and then create my Worker by injecting ILogger.

But a few questions remains then:
How do I create the 3 classes my worker needs with their own logger?

```
public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
   {
      var obj1 = new Class1(/*here I dont have the proper Logger*/);
   }

public Class1(ILogger<Class1> logger){...}
```

An answer to that would be to pass an ILoggerFactory to be able to instantiate logger through the dependency tree, but that's not what is advised.

The other thing that is unclear in that example is which DI container to use and how to use it in my Worker class.
Because the ApplicationBuilder then allows to avoid explicitly passing the factory to each level of my dependency.

Here what I can read would be to pass a ServiceCollection, but in that case what is the gain compared to passing the factory interface ?

Comment: _"I'm supposed to do something like this in the entry point of my class library"_ says who? Just ctor-inject `ILogger<YourClass>` in the library classes and that's it. Logger config is done in consuming applications / projects.

Comment: "I'm supposed to do something like this in the entry point of my class library". No, class libraries should not refer to the DI Container. Class libraries should simply apply the Constructor Injection pattern. Only the startup project should depend on the DI Container, and should configure the applications components. This is called the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass this as a parameters, just put

```
private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
```

Inside your class then use like

```
_logger.LogInformation("Test");
```

And you are already using dependency injection, because all the configuration is done in the *appsettings.{Environment}.json* file.

Complete example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line).